# ¿Por qué el programa solo me deja escribir una nota en el archivo .wav?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Verán estoy haciendo un programa que permite crear una canción y genera un archivo .wav de lo que estoy creando! Lo que hago es que recibo la frecuencia de las notas del usuario y la duración de cada una de esas frecuencias, luego las meto en un arreglo para reproducirlas unificadas y synthesizer me crea la onda de sonido y me permite reproducirla y escribirla el archivo .wav, el problema es que solo me guarda una nota dentro del archivo wav. Creo que sobrescribe en el archivo pero no sé como arreglarlo.
 Este es mi código:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize  
from synthesizer import Player, Synthesizer, Waveform
from synthesizer import Writer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import ast


control = 15.00


#------------------------------Función que genera sonido--------------------------------------

def sonido(textoC): 
    cadena2 = textoC
    cadena = []
    cadena3 = []
    valorNotas = []
    valorDuracion = []
    bandera = 0
    nota = ""
    duracion = ""
    frecuenciaN = []
    frecuenciaD = []
    x = 0
    tempo = 0
    Dire  = os.path.dirname (os.path.abspath ( __file__ ))
    for carac in cadena2:
        if carac == "n":
            bandera = 1
        if carac == "d":
            bandera = 2
        if bandera == 1:
            nota = nota + carac
        if bandera == 2:
            duracion = duracion + carac
    cadena = nota.split("n")
    cadena3 = duracion.split("d")
    for valor in cadena:
        if valor != "" and valor != ":":
            if valor != "c" and valor !="i" and valor !="o" and valor != "\n":
                valorNotas.append(valor)
    for valor in cadena3:
        if valor != "" and valor != "\n":
            valorDuracion.append(valor)

    tamanio = len(valorNotas)
    tamanio = tamanio - 1
    while x < tamanio:
        try:
            frecuenciaD = float(valorDuracion[x])
            frecuenciaN = float(valorNotas[x])
            tempo = tempo + frecuenciaD
            print (tempo)
            writer = Writer()
            player = Player()
            player.open_stream()
            synthesizer = Synthesizer(osc1_waveform=Waveform.sine, osc1_volume=1.0, use_osc2=False)
            player.play_wave(synthesizer.generate_constant_wave(frecuenciaN, frecuenciaD))
            onda = synthesizer.generate_constant_wave(frecuenciaN, frecuenciaD)
            writer.write_waves (os.path.join ( Dire , " test.wav " ), onda)
            x = x+1
            if tempo == control:
                x = tamanio   
        except:
            x = x+1
```

Nota: Para reproducir el sonido estoy utilizando synthesizer, que me crea una onda con la frecuencia y duración que le mando.

Comment: Prueba a ir guardando cada `onda` en una `lista` durante el bucle, y cuando salgas del bucle volcar esa lista a fichero usando `writer.write_waves(fichero, *lista)`. He visto en la documentación que admite como segundo parámetro una lista (desempaquetada con el asterisco) y las volcaría concatenadas al fichero.

Comment: Gracias! me funcionó perfectamente!!